# path join error for python os.walk script

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7

I cobbled together a script that walks through a directory and uploads the contents to a postgres DB.

It mostly works, except I am hitting an error with some of the files -- and not others.  I successfully load 43 files before hitting this error.

This is the error I'm hitting -- it looks like it's doubling the "\" in the path name of the file it throws the error for:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uploader_script.py", line 136, in <module>
    main()
  File "uploader_script.py", line 69, in main
    filestat = os.stat(os.path.join(root, name))
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Data\\04-09-2018-upload\\Data - Educational - Statistics - Standardized Exam Scores\\United States\\Data - Minnesota\\The Act - Profile Report - State Graduating Class 2016 Minnesota [MN_ACT_Profile_Report]\\._The Act - Profile Report - State Graduating Class 2016 Minnesota [MN_ACT_Profile_Report].pdf'
```

This is my code:

```
"""A tool for saving files to and from a postgresql db.

            *** THIS IS WRITTEN FOR PYTHON 2.7 ***
"""

# To use it for the current directory, run this in the command line:
# python uploader_script.py .\ --store


import os
import sys
import argparse
import psycopg2
import time
import datetime
import msvcrt as m

db_conn_str = "postgresql://xxx:xxx@111.11.111.1:5432/DBname"

# Define your table schema
create_table_stm = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_warehouse (
    id serial primary key,
    orig_filename text not null,
    file_extension text not null,
    created_date date not null,
    last_modified_date date not null,
    upload_timestamp_UTC timestamp not null,
    uploaded_by text not null,
    file_size_in_bytes integer not null,
    original_containing_folder text not null,
    file_data bytea not null
)
"""

# raw_input will be different in python3
uploaded_by = raw_input("Please, enter your [Firstname] [Lastname]: ")

if not uploaded_by:
    print "You did not enter your name.  Press ENTER to exit this script, then attempt to run the script again."
    m.getch()
    exit()
else:
    print "Thank you, " + uploaded_by + "! Please, press ENTER to upload the files."
    m.getch()

# Walk through the directory
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser_action = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    parser_action.add_argument("--store", action='store_const', const=True, help="Load an image from the named file and save it in the DB")
    parser_action.add_argument("--fetch", type=int, help="Fetch an image from the DB and store it in the named file, overwriting it if it exists. Takes the database file identifier as an argument.", metavar='42')
    parser.add_argument("parentdir", help="Name of folder to write to / fetch from")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    conn = psycopg2.connect(db_conn_str)
    curs = conn.cursor()

    # Run the create_table_stm code at the top of this file to generate the table if it does not already exist
    curs.execute(create_table_stm)

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args.parentdir):
        for name in files:
            # Store the original file path from the computer the file was uploaded from.
            joined_var = os.path.join(root)
            original_path = os.path.abspath(joined_var)

            # Set the file the script is looking at to a variable for later use to pull filesize
            filestat = os.stat(os.path.join(root, name))

            # Split the file extension from the filename
            file_extension_holder = os.path.splitext(name)[1]

            # Time module: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#module-time
            # The return value is a number giving the number of seconds since the epoch (see the time module).
            # The epoch is the point where the time starts, and is platform dependent. For Windows and Unix, the epoch is January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 (UTC). 
            # To find out what the epoch is on a given platform, look at time.gmtime(0).  The code below is written for Windows.

            # Datetime module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

            # More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python            

            # Generate the created_date -- I suspect there is a more straightforward way to do this with the time or datetime module.  But this works.
            c_time_in_seconds = os.path.getctime(os.path.join(root, name))
            c_time_array = str(time.gmtime(c_time_in_seconds)[:3])
            c_date_str = ''.join(c_time_array)
            c_format_str = '(%Y, %m, %d)' 
            c_datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(c_date_str, c_format_str)
            created_date = c_datetime_obj.date()

            # Generate the last_modified_date
            m_time_in_seconds = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, name))
            m_time_array = str(time.gmtime(m_time_in_seconds)[:3])
            m_date_str = ''.join(m_time_array)
            m_format_str = '(%Y, %m, %d)' 
            m_datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(m_date_str, m_format_str)
            last_modified_date = m_datetime_obj.date()

            # Generate the timestamp of the upload (in UTC timezone)
            py_uploaded_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()



            if args.store:
                with open(os.path.join(root, name),'rb') as f:

                    # read the binary 
                    filedata = psycopg2.Binary(f.read())

                    # Call the st_size command from os.stat to read the filesize in bytes
                    filesize = filestat.st_size

                    # This has to agree with the table schema you set at the top of this file
                    curs.execute("INSERT INTO data_warehouse(id, orig_filename, file_extension, created_date, last_modified_date, upload_timestamp_UTC, uploaded_by, file_size_in_bytes, original_containing_folder, file_data) VALUES (DEFAULT,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) RETURNING id", (name, file_extension_holder, created_date, last_modified_date, py_uploaded_timestamp, uploaded_by, filesize, original_path, filedata))
                    print curs
                    returned_id = curs.fetchone()[0]
                print("Stored {0} into DB record {1}".format(args.parentdir, returned_id))
                conn.commit()

            elif args.fetch is not None:
                with open(args.parentdir,'wb') as f:
                    curs.execute("SELECT file_data, orig_filename FROM files WHERE id = %s", (int(args.fetch),))
                    (file_data, orig_parentdir) = curs.fetchone()
                    f.write(file_data)
                print("Fetched {0} into file {1}; original parentdir was {2}".format(args.fetch, args.parentdir, orig_filename))




        for name in dirs:
            print(os.path.join(root, name))

    conn.close()        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried norming the path first, with `normpath`?

Comment: As in, path.normpath(original_path) ?

Comment: I just tried normpath and it hasn't worked.

Comment: Maybe the "dot" at the beginning of the filename is confusing Windows? Rename that file to leave only the dot before the extension and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I don't know where it's getting the dot from -- this is the filename in the folder: The Act - Profile Report - State Graduating Class 2016 Minnesota [MN_ACT_Profile_Report].pdf